# How do I flip specific bits in a specific spot and carry the value to do it again later in the program

Tags: c, embedded

my plan is to set PORTA= 0x0F thus PORTA= 00001111 and then flipping the signs in PORTC in the if loop so now PORT C is 00001111 then another if loop saying if PORTC’s 0-3 = 1 then set PORTC7=1 showing as PORTC=10001111

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#ifdef _SIMULATE_
#include "simAVRHeader.h"
#endif

int main(void) {
    DDRA = 0x00; PORTA = 0xFF; // Configure port A's 8 pins as inputs
    DDRC = 0xFF; PORTC = 0x00; // Configure port C's 8 pins as outputs, initialize to 0s
    while (1)
{


    if(!(PINA & 0x01)){
        PORTC |= 0x01;
    }
    if(!(PINA & 0x02)){
        PORTC |= 0x02;
    }
    if(!(PINA & 0x04)){
        PORTC |= 0x04;
        }
    if(!(PINA & 0x08)){
        PORTC |= 0x08;
        }

    if(PORTC==0x0F)
    {
        PORTC |= 0x80;
    }
    

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `PORTA` is initialized to `0x11111111` according to the code. Do you want this initialization and then setting it to `0x00001111`. Is it ok if you flip all 4 least significant bits of `PORTC` at once? Or you want to do it one by one, as in the code shown?

Comment: im doing a test cases seperatly but for example if PORT A is: 0000 1111 then PORT C should be 0000 0000

Comment: If you want to set PORTC pins when the corresponding PORTA pins are low, then you must write `if(PINA & 0x01)`. Not sure why you included the `!` there.

Answer (score 0):

To enable a bit use OR (`|`) with that bit.

To disable a bit use AND (`&`) with everything but that bit using bitwise NOT (`~`).

To change a bit's value (0 to 1 or 1 to 0) use bitwise XOR (`^`).

Here's an example:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

int main ()
{
  uint8_t bits = 0x00;
  uint8_t mask = 0x01;
  //enable bit
  bits |= mask;
  //disable bit
  bits &= ~mask;
  //flip bit
  bits ^= mask;
  //flip bit again
  bits ^= mask;
  return 0;
}
```